# Disable extensions to run script on website

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, javascript-injection

Some extensions are modifying the HTML and inserting their own scripts in the website.

Is there a way to disallow extensions to run scripts on my website?

I tried with CSP, but it doesn't seem to work.

Edit: To remove the ambiguity.
This question is asked from the point of view of a website owner. Let's say I create a website and publish it. Now as a website owner, is there a way I can control/disallow browser extensions to run their code on my website?

Comment: No, you can't. The only way is to set local policies by the user's network administrator.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can from google "Admin console".

From Google:
"You can allow or block all apps from modifying webpages that you specify. Or, you can allow or block specific apps. Typically, admins set a combination of policies. For example, you might follow the first set of steps below to block apps in general from altering your webpages. Then, follow the next steps to allow specific apps to alter them as exceptions."

You have here examples and and more explanations: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9031935?hl=en

Comment: Not relevant. This is for local network administration. Sites can't do it. The question was slightly ambiguous, I admit, so it misled you.